# How to change icons onPress in React Native [ListView]

Tags: android, listview, react-native, react-native-listview

I am new to React Native so excuse the question if this is simple. I am trying to toggle icons in a ListView. How should I go about this? Your help is much appreciated.

Here's a piece of code i'm working with.

```
this.state = {
  logo: 'star-o',
   check: false
};



 saveFavourite = (data) => {
   this.state.check === false ? this.setState({logo:'star', check:true}) : this.setState({logo:'star-o', check:false})
} 


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.saveFavourite(data)}>
   <Icon name={this.state.logo} size={30} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

it din't change the icon.

Answer (score 0):

First I can guess by your code that you are addressing this in the component holding the list view. This is wrong because you cant define a state to every "loveable" component, mainly because you cannot know how many are they beforehand. Instead, you should try to make this component dummy and receive if it is loved or not by props.

Then you should put a callback inside your component to execute code from your parent Component. Something like this:

```
class MyListComponent extends React.Component {
   state = {
     items: [
        { text: 'Some text', loved: false },
        { text: 'Some text2', loved: true },
     ],
   }

   toggleLoved() => {
     // your logic here
   }

   render() {
     return(
       <FlatList
          data={this.state.items}
          renderItem={(item) => {
              <MyLoveableComponent
                loved={item.item.loved}
                onLoved={ () => this.toggleLoved() }
          }/>
      );
   }

}




const MyLoveableComponent = ({ loved, onLoved, logo }) => {
      return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={() => {
               setFavourite();
               onLoved();
        }>
          <Icon name={logo} size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>);
    }
}
```

Check the component-container design pattern and remind that components should be as dummy as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it out and let you know

Comment: It's a big refactor you have there. Any doubts just post a comment. If it worked for you remember to accept the answer ;)

Comment: How can I update this kind of data >     items: [
        { text: 'Some text', loved: false },
        { text: 'Some text2', loved: true },
     ]
if I stored it as a local json file?

Comment: You should try to store those values in AsyncStorage or maybe use Redux and Redux-Persist to do so. If not your data will be forever static.

Comment: currently I store my data like this (data.js)  items: [
        { text: 'Some text', loved: false },
        { text: 'Some text2', loved: false},
     ],

and when I press the saveFavourite() it will store that into AsyncStorage and update loved:true. Am I doing this right?

Comment: No, you are not. In component will mount check if there is data in AsyncStorage. If there is no data, load the default values from your.js file. If there is data load the one from aasyncStorage. Every time you change an icon, update the loved key in your component state and then save that state into asyncStorage (and that state will be the one you load from component will mount on next startup)

Comment: Im on my phone now, forgive my spelling please.

Comment: I have two screens[Home, Favourite] to load data. Home loads data from local file[data.js] like image above. Favourite loads data from AsyncStorage that item has loved set to true[loved:true] and icon should changed too. So how can I show item that is in Favourite inside Home too? If in Home I load data from AsyncStorage so users have no default item to select.

Comment: Same process, load data from asyncStorage in component will mount and use array.filter and show them just the liked ones with array.map or a flatlist taking the filtered array. That is out  the scope of the questio n btw. It it has been solved close this one and open a new one.

Comment: A pleasure. Ask your doubts in a new one ;)

Comment: The code you put shold work. What do you need me to update?

Comment: probably because you are using this inside a functional component. Remember that you can't declare methods inside a functional component, you must declare them outside, in the same file, and you must call them without this. Editing, happens when copying and pasting code hehe